# Datagridview Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview

This is my file (test.csv) which was saved by datagridview, the code below reads the file and paste all the values into datagridview.

```
InitializeComponent();
try
{
   //gbSeries.Enabled = false;
   //AssignValues();
   //btnSave.Enabled = true;

   // read and insert a new line
   System.IO.StreamReader csv_file = File.OpenText("c:/test.csv");

   while (csv_file.Peek() >= 0)
   {
      // read and add a line
      string line = csv_file.ReadLine();
      string[] vals = line.Split(';');

      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] 
      { 
         vals[0],
         vals[1],
         vals[2],
         vals[3],
         vals[4],
         vals[5],
         vals[6],
         vals[7]
         //cansim,
         //freeze });
      });
   }
   csv_file.Close();
}
```

I save my datagrid view data like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter csvFileWriter = new StreamWriter(CsvFpath, false);
        string columnHeaderText = "";
        int countColumn = dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1;

        if (countColumn >= 0)
        {
            columnHeaderText = dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
        {
            columnHeaderText = columnHeaderText + ';' + dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        }

        csvFileWriter.WriteLine(columnHeaderText);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataRowObject in dataGridView1.Rows)
            dataGridView1.Rows = 1;
        {
            if (!dataRowObject.IsNewRow)
            {
                string dataFromGrid = "";
                dataFromGrid = dataRowObject.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
                {
                    dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ';' + dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                }
                csvFileWriter.WriteLine(dataFromGrid);
            }
        }
        csvFileWriter.Flush();
        csvFileWriter.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exceptionObject)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.ToString()); // If I don't have a value in the column then it throws exception. I don't want that. 
    }
}
```

The first row which contains names of columns, I just want to save it once for all time. The problem is, every single time when i edit my datagridview and save it. The first row which contains names of colums (as said before) comes twice and if I edit again and again it gets rownames + 1 bigger everytime.

```
first time:
Row names ---------
data --------------

After editing:

Row names ---------
Row names ---------
data --------------

After editing:

Row names ---------
Row names ---------
Row names ---------
data --------------
```

---

All my datagridview columns need to have a value, before I can save my data. But I want to save data with empty columns also, is there anything I can do?? When there is a empty column it throws an exception and then all my data is GONE!

```
MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.ToString()); // If I don't have a value in the column then it throws exception. I don't want that.
```

How should I save the first line/row once and not everytime. And when I read file back into datagridview, I don't want to read the first row which contains names ( which is already there).